# SQL Server: Check Upper Case or Lower Case after certain Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2012

I have data like `'John is my name; Ram is my name; Adam is my name'`.

My rule is such that every first letter that comes after `;` should be capital letter.

How do I select all values that satisfy the rule?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Shnugo Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)

Comment: This is going to be an ugly problem, especially if the number of semicolon-separated terms is unknown.  A better solution would be to normalize your data and get each name/sentence on a separate record.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can't there be a regular expression solution?

Comment: Sadly, SQL Server is known for having poor native regex support.  But this would be easy to handle using something like C# or Java.  Have you considered such an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers show how to transform rows into something that matches your pattern.

If you just want to `select` the rows that match the pattern you are describing, you can use `patindex()` or `like` with a case sensitive collation (or use `collate` to apply one).

This assumes that in addition to the rule that every letter that follows a semicolon must be a capital letter, that the very first letter should also be capital. If that is not the case, just remove the first clause in the `where`.

```
select *
from t
where patindex('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%', val collate latin1_general_cs_as) = 1
  and patindex('%; [^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%', val collate latin1_general_cs_as) = 0
```

---

```
select *
from t
where val collate latin1_general_cs_as like '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%'
  and val collate latin1_general_cs_as not like '%; [^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%'
```

---

test setup:

```
create table t (id int not null identity(1,1),val varchar(256))
insert into t values 
 ('John is my name; Ram is my name; Adam is my name')
,('john is my name; ram is my name; adam is my name')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DBGIS10645

Both of the above return:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
| id |                       val                        |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | John is my name; Ram is my name; Adam is my name |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You might split this with the XML trick like this

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='John is my name; Ram is my name; Adam is my name';
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(@YourString,'; ','$$SplitHere$$') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'$$SplitHere$$','</x><x>')+ '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted
)
,DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PartNr
           ,x.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Part
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes(N'/x') AS X(x)
)
SELECT PartNr
      ,Part
      ,CASE WHEN ASCII(LEFT(Part,1)) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FirstIsCapital
FROM DerivedTable;
```

The result

```
Nr  Part            FirstLetterIsCaptial
---------------------------------------- 
1   John is my name     1
2   Ram is my name      1
3   Adam is my name     1
```

I do not know what your final goal is... Find parts, where the first letter is not capital? Make sure, that your rule is fullfilled?

However:
**Best was, to use this to correct your design and place these parts in a `1:n` related side table**.

Comment: Use following source string for testing purpose: `'John is my name;   Ram is my name;    Adam is my name'`

Comment: @BogdanSahlean , Well  I'd use `L/RTRIM()` ... The error is the storage format ... Any code to solve this will be a hack...

Comment: `TRIM` was introduced in SQL Server 2017. What if source string is  `'!John is my name;!Ram is my name;!Adam is my name;¡Hola!'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Little bit of ugly solution but you can give a try...

```
Declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'John is my name; Ram is my name; Adam is my name'

Declare @xml as xml
Set @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,';' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)
Select * from (
    Select RowN = Row_Number() over (order by (SELECT NULL)), LTrim(RTrim(N.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'))) as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N) -- this is to split if you are using sql server 2016 you can use string_Split
) a
Where unicode(substring(a.[value],1,1)) = unicode(upper(substring(a.[value],1,1)))
```

Idea is to split the string and check with unicode value to see whether it is upper or not

Comment: This solution has one big flaw: If your `@str` contains forbidden characters it will break...

Comment: Just try it with `'John is my name; Jim & Tom are my friends'`

Comment: Got you... Nice learning as I did not came across this earlier... Thanks Shnugo...

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function like this.

```
Create FUNCTION SPLITTER (    
    @textData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX) ) RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE  (
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX) )  AS BEGIN 
    DECLARE @index INT  DECLARE @data nvarchar(1000)    DECLARE @firstCharacter char
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@textData)

    WHILE (@index>0)
    BEGIN
                set @data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@textData, 1, @index - 1)))       set @firstCharacter = SUBSTRING(@data,1,1);
                if UNICODE(@firstCharacter) = UNICODE(upper(@firstCharacter))       begin           INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) SELECT @data       end;

        SET @textData = SUBSTRING(@textData, @index + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2, LEN(@textData))

        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @textData)
    END
        set @data = @textData   set @firstCharacter = SUBSTRING(@data,1,1);
            if UNICODE(@firstCharacter) = UNICODE(upper(@firstCharacter))   begin       INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) SELECT @data   end;

    RETURN END
```

use it like this

> select * from SPLITTER ('John is my name; Ram is my name; Adam is my name', ';')

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a copy of [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) and do this:

```
-- note that I made the 3rd item start with lower-case
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='John is my name; Ram is my name; adam is my name';

WITH D(n) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT position 
  FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@yourstring,1) WHERE token = ';'
),
TOKEN(token) AS
(
  SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@YourString, N+1, 
           ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(';', @YourString, N+1),0), 101)-(N+1)))
  FROM D
)
SELECT token,
       FirstLetterIsCaptial = IIF(ASCII(SUBSTRING(token,1,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90, 1, 0)
FROM TOKEN;
```

**Results**

```
token              FirstLetterIsCaptial
------------------ --------------------
John is my name    1
Ram is my name     1
adam is my name    0
```